# unable to install anything using apt-get because of insserv

Tags: ubuntu, startup, cups, init-script

Whenever I try to install something using `apt-get` I get the error messages involving `insserv`. I have tried install many different packages but everything give same error. And apparently, CUPS package is doing/has done something because every error message involves it. The following are the errors displayed when I ran `sudo apt-get install wine1.8 winetricks`:

```
After this operation, 716 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
Setting up util-linux (2.27.1-6ubuntu3.1) ...
insserv: warning: script 'K01cups-browsed' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'cups-browsed' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop at service plymouth if started
insserv: There is a loop between service plymouth and procps if started
insserv:  loop involving service procps at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service udev at depth 1
insserv: Starting cups-browsed depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups-browsed depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups-browsed depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups-browsed depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups-browsed depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups-browsed depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups-browsed depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups-browsed depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups-browsed depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups-browsed depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups-browsed depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups-browsed depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups-browsed depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups-browsed depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups-browsed depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups-browsed depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups-browsed depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups-browsed depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups-browsed depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups-browsed depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups-browsed depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups-browsed depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups-browsed depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups-browsed depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups-browsed depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups-browsed depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups-browsed depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups-browsed depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups-browsed depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups-browsed depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups-browsed depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups-browsed depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups-browsed depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups-browsed depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups-browsed depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups-browsed depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups-browsed depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups-browsed depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups-browsed depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups-browsed depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups-browsed depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups-browsed depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups-browsed depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups-browsed depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups-browsed depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups-browsed depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups-browsed depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups-browsed depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups-browsed depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Max recursions depth 99 reached
insserv:  loop involving service speech-dispatcher at depth 1
insserv: Starting cups-browsed depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups-browsed depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups-browsed depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups-browsed depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups-browsed depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups-browsed depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups-browsed depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups-browsed depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups-browsed depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups-browsed depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups-browsed depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups-browsed depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups-browsed depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups-browsed depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups-browsed depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups-browsed depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups-browsed depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups-browsed depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups-browsed depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups-browsed depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups-browsed depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups-browsed depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop between service cups-browsed and hwclock if started
insserv:  loop involving service hwclock at depth 1
insserv: There is a loop at service cups-browsed if started
insserv:  loop involving service networking at depth 4
insserv: There is a loop between service plymouth and urandom if started
insserv:  loop involving service urandom at depth 4
insserv:  loop involving service mountdevsubfs at depth 2
insserv: Starting cups-browsed depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups-browsed depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups-browsed depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups-browsed depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups-browsed depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups-browsed depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups-browsed depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups-browsed depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups-browsed depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups-browsed depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups-browsed depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop between service cups-browsed and dns-clean if started
insserv:  loop involving service dns-clean at depth 1
insserv: Starting cups-browsed depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups-browsed depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package util-linux (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 util-linux
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The contents of /etc/insserv.conf are as follows:

```
#
# All local filesystems are mounted (done during boot phase)
#
$local_fs   +umountfs

#
# Low level networking (ethernet card)
#
$network    +networking

#
# Named is operational
#
$named      +named +dnsmasq +lwresd +bind9 +unbound $network

#
# All remote filesystems are mounted (note in some cases /usr may
# be remote. Most applications that care will probably require
# both $local_fs and $remote_fs)
#
$remote_fs  $local_fs +umountnfs +sendsigs

#
# System logger is operational
#
$syslog     +rsyslog +sysklogd +syslog-ng +dsyslog +inetutils-syslogd

#
# The system time has been set correctly
#
$time       +hwclock

#
# Services which need to be interactive
#
<interactive>   glibc udev console-screen keymap keyboard-setup console-setup cryptdisks cryptdisks-early checkfs-loop
```

output for `$ apt-cache policy cups-browsed plymouth dns-clean`

```
cups-browsed:
  Installed: 1.8.3-2ubuntu3
  Candidate: 1.8.3-2ubuntu3
  Version table:
 *** 1.8.3-2ubuntu3 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
plymouth:
  Installed: 0.9.2-3ubuntu13
  Candidate: 0.9.2-3ubuntu13.1
  Version table:
     0.9.2-3ubuntu13.1 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
 *** 0.9.2-3ubuntu13 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
N: Unable to locate package dns-clean
```

I don't know any other relevant information that might be important for solving this, that's why I haven't posted it. If you want more info, please feel free to ask.

Comment: Check to make sure you don't have anything goofy in insserv's configuration, particularly /etc/insserv.conf and /etc/insserv.conf.d/*. If you are unsure, add the contents of those files to the question.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I have added the contents of `/etc/insserv.conf`

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? Have you added any software that's not a package from the "standard" repositories? What about recent editing of system files?

Comment: @roaima Ubuntu version 16.04. Yes I had added the pinta repository, then nixnote2 and then wine1.8. I haven't edited any system files

Comment: `apt-cache policy cups-browsed plymouth dns-clean`, please. And add any other packages that you think might be relevant.

Comment: @FaheemMitha I have added the output of the command you told. No I can't think of other relevant packages. I note that this problem can right after I tried install nixnote2 from debian installer. The package was broken and I removed it.

Comment: You need to look at files in `/etc/insserv.conf.d`. Post the content of any file whose name contains `dns`, `plymouth` or `cups`. Or maybe other files, the problem isn't with a single file but with them in combination, they create a loop where A must be started before B must be started before C must be … must be started before A.

Comment: @Gilles There are no files in `/etc/insserv.conf.d`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

#### First of all, the problem is that you are stuck at the boot sequencing.

---

The boot sequencing method is decided during installation or upgrades. If there are no **loops in the dependencies** declared by the LSB headers of all installed `init.d` scripts and no **obsolete scripts**, the system is converted to dependency based boot sequence.

---

We have to check for

1. **Loop in dependencies**: Occurs when >

   - There are missing LSB tags in some scripts or error in LSB tags like missing  `Required-Start:` or `Required-Stop:` tags
   - Some scripts depend on other scripts which depend on the system facility `$all` which cannot be true. Because the scripts depending on `$all` is loaded last at starting. Since it loads last, nothing can depend on it. Hence, messes up the dependency based boot sequence.
2. **Obsolete scripts**: Occur when

   - Some packages being upgraded to newer versions which may not use a script in `/etc/init.d/` and the maintainer may have missed the code to remove the old script. *Not our mistake.*

The cause is surely foreign. Goto `/etc/init.d` and view the file corresponding to `cups-browsed` and confirm that it have an LSB comment with `Provides`,`Required-Start`/`Required-Stop` (at least empty),`Default-Start`/`Default-Stop` in it like below.

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides :          cups-browsed
# Required-Start :
# Required-Stop :
# Default-Start :     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop  :     0 1 6
# Short-Description : Some info
# Description :       Some more info
### END INIT INFO
```

If it's not there you have choice to add the LSB comment or completely purge the program and scripts from `/etc/init.d/` and `/etc/rc?` files.
Hope this would work.

*Feel free to ask if you have any doubts.*

Comment: It has been more than a month after I posted the question. As I didn't get any answer at that time, I purged the program and everything worked. Now I have again installed `cups` and mysteriously everything is working fine. I am still accepting yours as correct answer because you have mentioned the purge program suggestion in it.

Comment: I am having the same issue. I checked the `/etc/init.d/cups-browsed` file and it already has the comments as you mentioned. How do i purge the program and scripts  ?

Comment: Ok, I understand, but what I don't understand is why? These INIT INFO headers had existed for more than a decade but nobody cared about them. From a human point of view having two digits from 0 to 99 is a very clear way to establish startup order but now I have to trace Required-Start headers? Why? Sometimes less is more.

Comment: Ubuntu does not like the blank spaces before the colons.